# Reading and writing into files

Tags: c++, file

Consider my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Mjerenje
{
    int dan, mjesec, godina;
    string s;
    vector<double> v;
    double prosjek;
    double minimalna;
    double maximalna;
};

int main ()
{
    ifstream ulazni_tok("TEMPERATURE.TXT");
    if(!ulazni_tok) cout<<"Datoteka TEMPERATURE.TXT ne postoji!\n";
    vector<Mjerenje> Mjerenja;
    for(;;)
    {
        int dan, mjesec, godina;
        double temp;
        char c;
        string s;
        vector<double> v;
        ulazni_tok>>dan>>c>>mjesec>>c>>godina;
        getline(ulazni_tok, s);
        while(ulazni_tok>>temp)
        {
        v.push_back(temp);
        ulazni_tok>>c;
        if(c!=',') break;
        }
        ulazni_tok.clear();
        double prosjek(0);
        double minimalna=v[0]; //My program crashes here
        double maximalna=v[0];
        for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
        {
            if(v[i]<minimalna)
                minimalna=v[i];
            if(v[i]>maximalna)
                maximalna=v[i];
            prosjek+=v[i];
        }
        prosjek/=v.size();
        Mjerenja.push_back({dan, mjesec, godina, s, v, prosjek, minimalna, maximalna});
        sort(Mjerenja.begin(), Mjerenja.end(), [](Mjerenje a, Mjerenje b){if(a.godina<b.godina)return true; else if(a.godina==b.godina && a.mjesec<b.mjesec)return true; else if(a.godina==b.godina && a.mjesec==b.mjesec && a.dan<b.dan)return true; else if(a.godina==b.godina && a.mjesec==b.mjesec && a.dan==b.dan && a.prosjek<b.prosjek)return true; else return false;});
        if(!ulazni_tok) break;
    }
    if(ulazni_tok.bad()) cout<<"Problem pri citanju datoteke TEMPERATURE.TXT\n";
    ofstream izlazni_tok("IZVJESTAJ.TXT");
    for(int i=0; i<Mjerenja.size(); i++)
    {
        izlazni_tok<<Mjerenja[i].s<<endl;
        for(int j=0; j<Mjerenja[i].s.size(); j++)
            izlazni_tok<<"-";
        izlazni_tok<<"Datum mjerenja: "<<Mjerenja[i].dan<<"/"<<Mjerenja[i].mjesec<<"/"<<Mjerenja[i].godina<<endl;
        izlazni_tok<<"Minimalna temperatura: "<<Mjerenja[i].minimalna<<endl;
        izlazni_tok<<"Maksimalna temperatura: "<<Mjerenja[i].maximalna<<endl;
        izlazni_tok<<"Prosjecna temperatura: "<<Mjerenja[i].prosjek<<endl;
        izlazni_tok<<endl;
    }
    izlazni_tok.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is how my file "TEMPERATURE.TXT" looks like:

```
23/5/2016
Meteoroloska stanica Bjelave
7,12,16,20,18,13,6
9/11/2014
Mobilno mjerno mjesto Aerodrom, stanica II
-1,3,6,10,8
9/11/2014
Meteoroloska opservatorija Bjelasnica
-5,-2,0,3,1,2,-1,-4
```

What i wanted to do is to read from the file "TEMPERATURE.TXT" and after that to write some info into the file "IZVJESTAJ.TXT" like the highest, lowest and average temperature and so on. For some odd reason my program crashes in the line where i set my minimum temperature on the first temperature of my vector of temperatures and I have no idea why. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I fixed this, I just added: if(v.size()>0)
        {
            minimalna=v[0];
            maximalna=v[0];
        } but now my program crashes in the line where I make my struct Mjerenja. That's weird huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
  ulazni_tok>>dan>>c>>mjesec>>c>>godina;
```

you are not reading the entire line from your text file. That means that the subsequent line:

```
    getline(ulazni_tok, s);
```

does not read "Meteoroloska stanica Bjelave" into s, only the remainder of the date line above (wich is pretty much empty)

Therefore, the line

```
    while(ulazni_tok>>temp)
```

will now try to interpret "Meteoroloska stanica Bjelave" as a double, which will fail and the while loop will exit before anything is inserted into v.

Subsequently you are trying to access an element in a vector that does not exist, and hence the crash.

Comment: @Vito By the way. Line 41 (or thereabout) that reads ulazni_tok.clear();. Shouldn't that be ulazni_tok.unget(); instead? At least that made the program write output and terminate correctly for me.